# QML: monitoring mouse moving event in the "whole" window

Tags: qt, qml

> Hmm... maybe this task should be implemented in C++? I don't know...

I'm using QML to making a media-player like (e.g. QuickTime in OSX) interface, which can detect mouse event:

When mouse idle for a period, hide all control panels and show only `VideoOutput`. Or as soon as mouse out of the window, do the same things immediately.

So my requirements are:

1. monitor mouse move event within the **whole window**
2. don't block original mouse event on any other component.

Or more precisely, see pseudo code:

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: applicationWindow  // <- This is wrong and will throw error
    hoverEnabled: true

    /* After reading the Qt doc, this property seems should be
    placed in a MouseArea, which is under another MouseArea.
    When child has mouse event, it propagate up to parent MouseArea.
    So this should be also wrong. */
    propagateComposedEvents: true
    onClicked: mouse.accepted = false;
    onPressed: mouse.accepted = false;
    onReleased: mouse.accepted = false;
    onDoubleClicked: mouse.accepted = false;
    onPressAndHold: mouse.accepted = false;
    onPositionChanged: {
        console.log("moved!", mouse.x, mouse.y)
        mouse.accepted = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Place your `MouseArea` as the last child item of your window, than use `anchors.fill: parent`. `propagateComposedEvents` is not needed.

Comment: anchors.fill: applicationWindow.contentItem

Comment: If you want to look into a C++ solution, then  installing an event filter on the `QGuiApplication` object should to the trick. See `QObject::eventFilter()`

Comment: @Fabio You're correct! Place this as the last child works! Thank you!

Comment: @Fabio However I found this will cause some hovered-related components work incorrectly... Still unsolved... :S

Answer (score 3):

The Problem with QML is, that there are certain Event-Chains that you can either handle or leave it.

So if you want to handle the `clicked`-event in one MouseArea you can't propagate the `pressed`-event.

This however might be a sufficient solution:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 50
    height: 50
    color: 'orchid'
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

        drag.target: parent
    }
}

MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    hoverEnabled: true
    propagateComposedEvents: true
    onMouseXChanged: console.log(mouseX)
    onPressed: {
        mouse.accepted = false
    }
}
```

You handle the mouse-movement in the MouseArea that lies uppon everything else, while not handling anything as long as a button is pressed.

If you need information about the MouseMovement even then, you can create a singleton signal you... ring... in every other MouseArea you use... or propagate the signals through every qml-file of yours.

So instead of writing: `mouse.accepted = false` in every MouseArea you write: `mySingleton.mouseEventSignal()`. You might even add the Item and the coordinates, so you can then map the coordinates to what ever you want...

This might be sufficient for a fast and dirty prototype. For the real thing, maybe you need to do it in C++ as Kevin Krammer proposed